# Facebook insights API & CSV export date differences

Tags: facebook, date, facebook-insights

I've noticed a consistent discrepancy between the data returned from facebook insights when getting it from the API vs getting it CSV exporting. For example, for a certain metric (`page_impressions_unique_days_28`), the CSV reports:

```
2011/11/28 -> 374
2011/11/29 -> 355
2011/11/30 -> 341
```

While the API reports:

```
Tue, 29 Nov 2011 00:00:00 PST -08:00 -> 374
Wed, 30 Nov 2011 00:00:00 PST -08:00 -> 355
Thu, 01 Dec 2011 00:00:00 PST -08:00 -> 341
```

As you can see there's a 1 day offset. I'm in GMT+1, but converting the API dates to my timezone doesn't change the day:

```
Tue, 29 Nov 2011 09:00:00 CET +01:00 -> 374
Wed, 30 Nov 2011 09:00:00 CET +01:00 -> 355
Thu, 01 Dec 2011 09:00:00 CET +01:00 -> 341
```

Does anyone know what is going on here? Is it a timezone issue I haven't thought about? Or when the api reports the data for a day at midnight is it refering to full data of the previous day?

Thanks

Comment: I'm running into this issue as well. Unbelievable, yet I doubt there's a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. See that you are looking at an old date, I thought it was the spindle, but it seems a difference in api and export algorithm.